# Add Foreign Key to an existing column?

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello i am beginner in SQL and i have one question:

How to add new Column_B(int) which is foreign key to an existing Column_A(id) in same Table_A?

I tried this but i got Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE Table_A ADD COLUMN Column_B int;
ALTER TABLE Table_A 
ADD fk_Table_A FOREIGN KEY (Column_B) REFERENCES Table_A (Column_A);
```

Comment: `column_a` must be a primary key or have a unique constraint defined on it. You should also tell us which DBMS you are using.

Comment: my column_a doesnt have pk

Comment: Then you can't have a foreign key "pointing" to it.

Comment: i add pk to column_A and i have same error... ok doesnt matter^^

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @user307..- May be you are missing `constraint` keywork. Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table Table_A 
  ADD constraint fk_Table_A FOREIGN KEY (Column_B) REFERENCES Table_A (Column_A);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your references does not match. It can only add a foreign key when all the rows satisfy the foreign key condition, which is in your case that every value of `Column_B` is in `table_A.Column_A`.